# What's the difference between an External and an Internal ingress?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

In the context of Kubernetes and *Nginx ingress-controller*, I can't grasp the **difference between an *external* ingress and an *internal* ingress**.

- *what an *external* ingress and an *internal* ingress differ in?*
- *when should they be used and what use cases do they serve?*
- *when should one use `ingressClassName: nginx-internal`, `ingressClassName: nginx`, `metadata.annotations: [ kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-external ]` aut similis?*

I can't find much on the net, that discusses such difference or exemplifies how to use them. There's always some implicit knowledge assumed.

Comment: "nginx-internal" & "nginx-external" - these might be the names of the IngressClass resources and these can be used in annotation for ignoring an Ingress in case if you are using multiple ingress controllers. Check the below links if its helps.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/#using-ingressclasses

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor not really; I think the distinction is only theoretical, not technical or coming from Kubernetes context. Probably more related to your corporate network/architecture. An **External ingress** handles requests directly, while an **Internal ingress** is usually passed requests from a LoadBalancer. At least, this *seems* to be the meaning in the context of my company. The naming is only by convention, so ingress controllers don't step on each other (see last 2 pragraphs in https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both types allow ingress into the service in the ingress definition, but the external ingress will expose it to the internet.  The internal does not, it's only on the local subnet outside the kubernetes bubble.  Internal is used in situations where you need to allow a connection from another workload cluster on the same network but don't want it exposed to the internet.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good general description. And yes, I've figured out that such distinction was used in our company, although not referring to a specific document/spec.